# In java, Accessing synchronized objects

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

[Edited]
This is regarding the synchronization on an object in Java. I have a doubt and need clarification.

If I am accessing an object in both the threads simultaneously 
Accessing its method by one thread and in another thread re-initializing the object as null. 
Can this object can be synchronized?

Comment: Objects are not null. References are null. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "make an object null". If one thread accesses an object via a variable and another thread then sets that variable to null the first thread still has the reference to that object and can access it. If the second thread runs first, i.e. sets the variable to null, the first thread can't get that reference in the first place.

Example:

```
MyThreadsafeObject ref = new MyThreadsafeObject();

//start another thread and pass in the reference
new Thread( new MTOHandler( ref ) ).start(); 

ref = null; 

//start a 3rd thread and pass in the now-null reference
new Thread( new MTOHandler( ref ) ).start();
```

Here the first thread that is started can still use the object that has been passed while the second thread can't as it is getting a null reference.

If with your question you mean something like `synchronized( ref ) { ... }` then you'd be able to synchronize on the object as long as `ref` is not null when starting the block.